# Converting Height Map to Coordinates Java

Tags: java, javafx, colors, argb

I am trying to read a coloured heightmap specifically there one found [here](https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/images/GDEM-10km-colorized.png) into a set of coordinates for use in a triangle mesh. The problem is I don't know how to exactly convert the Argb values to a height scale from 0-255. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dind't know you exactly implementation but... I think you can get an idea from this:

```
rgb = 65536 * r + 256 * g + b;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The thing is I need to convert it to a single digit instead of the rgb components so that I can use them as coordinates. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Maybe you need this: rgb = 65536 * r + 256 * g + b; It's a little bit tricky.

Comment: So with the new answer, would I have to combine it with the numbers that you posted before in order to get it within the min-max range I need?